# jquery multiple functions each change

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

im trying to change some values based on some checkbox inputs, i've got it working, but only with 1 checkbox. I have a lot of code, so wont share it all, but any help would be great!

```
$('#polybags').change(function () {
        var polybags = this.checked ? "2" : "1";            
        console.log(polybags);
```

This value "2" or "1" is then used to calculate a value

```
var addOnPrice = Number(totalPrice)*Number(polybags);
```

If i close off the 1st change function, and start a new one, for a different checkbox, the whole script stops working, and nothing is calculated at all....and im struggling on how to get this sorted!

Ideally, im trying to achieve this :

```
$('#polybags').change(function () {
    var polybags = this.checked ? "2" : "1";            
    console.log(polybags);
$('#nylon').change(function () {
    var nylon = this.checked ? "10" : "5";            
    console.log(nylon);
var addOnPrice = Number(totalPrice)*Number(polybags)+Number(nylon);
```

Hope this makes some sense, and you guys can point me in the right direction! :)

Many thanks!

Comment: You defined `polybags` and `nylon` inside functions and they are `undefined` outside.

Answer (score 0):

you can define the variable out of the event callback ,like this:

```
    var polybags=1, nylon=5, addOnPrice;

    $('#polybags').change(function() {
        polybags = this.checked ? "2" : "1";
        console.log(polybags);
    });

    $('#nylon').change(function() {
        nylon = this.checked ? "10" : "5";
        console.log(nylon);
    });

    addOnPrice = Number(totalPrice) * Number(polybags) + Number(nylon);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid global variables. Instead, have a function that gets all the values from the elements and performs the calculation.

```
function calculateAddOnPrice() {
    var polybags = $('#polybags').is(':checked') ? "2" : "1";            
    console.log(polybags);

    var nylon = $('#nylon').is(':checked') ? "10" : "5";
    console.log(nylon);

    var addOnPrice = Number(totalPrice)*Number(polybags)+Number(nylon);
    console.log(addOnPrice);
}
```

Then call that function whenever an input changes:

```
$('#polybags').change(function() {
    calculateAddOnPrice();
});

$('#nylon').change(function() {
    calculateAddOnPrice();
});
```

You may also want to call the `calculateAddOnPrice()` function when the page first loads.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the answer, makes a lot of sense! BUT...i've given it a go, and i cant get the .change(functions() to work...

I would add my code here, but it'll be messy, so i pastebin'd it! Hope thats allowed....

https://pastebin.com/SfBRWNRF

Many thanks!

Comment: @EdwardHill - The calls to `.change()` should go outside the `calculateAddOnPrice()` function. They register the event handlers, so they need to execute when the page loads. You should be placing all the code in a document-ready handler.

Comment: @EdwardHill - Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmtmp4kt/) showing some example code in a document-ready handler. You would place that code in a `<script>` element, preferably in the `<head>` element.